# IntelliJ adds extra * every time I hit enter in a block comment

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javadoc, intellij-14

I'm having a super strange problem with Idea.

Every time I hit enter in a block comment it adds an extra * on the line. It gets really annoying to have to delete it before typing each line. 
I have tried importing several coworkers code style settings who are not having this issue to no avail. I also can't seem to find the setting that would be doing this, and nothing on google. Anyone know a setting that could be causing this?

Example:

```
 /**
 * Some comment (pressing enter 3 times)
 * 
 * 
 * (cursor is here)* * * * 
 */
```

Another Example:

```
/**
* Some comment (press enter)
* (cursor is here)*
*/
```

Comment: Sorry if I'm wrong here but that's how that comment is suppose to me, I think you're looking for    `/*
    Hello
     */` . Only have one start after the first forward slash.

Comment: @Brunaldo javadocs commonly start with 
/** see http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/index-137868.html

Comment: @rsavchenko The javadoc block style comments include the `*` on the newline and the javadoc compiler removes them. IntelliJ is following the convention.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch the one star is fine but each time i hit enter I get 2 3 4 5 *'s on the same line. So when I hit enter I get  * (cursor) * I don't   want the trailing star

Comment: @rsavchenko Ahh.. sounds like you edited the default configuration in the preferences... I'm not 100% sure howto reset that with intellij but I expect someone will know...

Comment: @rsavchenko Did you know you can format, `ctrl-alt-L`, and have your words auto fit the rows with the *s? Wondering if you don't like the *s because you go back and add text and manually format.

Comment: I am also seeing this behavior, and it began after a recent update. I doubt it has to do with any preference... and if it does, the update either changed a preference without asking me, or the update started interpreting a setting differently.

Comment: @DilumRanatunga it looks like it did have to do with a preference. I deleted my Intellij configuration directory and the problem went away. Sucks that I had to redo all my settings. But it must have been something in there, because when I import my old setting it comes back. Can't pinpoint the setting causing this though.

Comment: @NESPowerGlove sadly the auto format doesn't remove the extra **** characters.

Comment: @rsavchenko I meant that it would keep the asterisks but allow for easy typing of whatever you want, it would place them asterisks in for you, so you don't have to fight manually moving asterisks around when you wanted to add text in the middle of a preexisting comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect this is a defect/regression. I've created an issue on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-136673

---

**Update**

The IntelliJ team isolated the issue to Gauge plugin. I've logged the issue with plugin authors: https://github.com/getgauge/Intellij-Plugin/issues/39

Comment: This seems likely. Although It looks like it did have to do with a preference. I deleted my Intellij configuration directory and the problem went away. Sucks that I had to redo all my settings. But it must have been something in there, because when I import my old setting it comes back. Can't pinpoint the setting causing this though.

Comment: Thanks for the update @rsavchenko -- I guess I should now upload my settings to the ticket...

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it's a bug in the Gauge plugin I was using for ".md" file support. Uninstalled that and the issue was gone.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-136182

Answer (score 0):

What you're typing are not normal block comments (/* ... */) but Javadoc comments (/** ... */), and those *should* have a * at every line. So just delete the extra * after the first / and you'll be fine.

Comment: I wan't javadoc comments. The problem is not one star at each line. The problem is a star is added at every newline so u can get 2,3,4,5 etc *'s per line

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem recently. It turns out it was caused by the AWS Toolkit plugin.